# model binding and sumbit button mvc4

Tags: data-binding, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have multiple forms on a cshtml page. The first of these forms binds correctly, but I have not been able to get the second one to bind. Each time I click the submit button the passed values are all 0 or null (int and stings respectively)

My model contains two objects. AccountInfo and a list of AccountSettings:

```
public class AccountDetailViewRequest
{
    public Account AccountInfo { get; set; }
    public List<AccountSettings> Settings { get; set; }
}

public class AccountSettings
{
    public int AccountID;
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public int ID;
}
```

My actions. The first action that works correctly, but the second does not.

```
public ActionResult UpdateAccountDetails(Account model)
{...}

public ActionResult DeleteSetting(AccountSettings model)
{...}
```

In my cshtml page I have this block which works correctly

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAccountDetails", "Account"))
{ 
    <input type = "hidden" name = "AccountInfo.AcctID" value = @Model.AccountInfo.AcctID />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Company @Html.TextBox("AccountInfo.Company")</td>
            <--More text boxes here-->
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td><input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Later in the page I have this block. When I use the associated submit button the function is called, but the parameters are all 0 or null regardless of the content of the text boxes. The boxes populate properly from my DB when I view the source of the code.

```
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Settings.Count; index++)
{
    var setting = Model.Settings[index];
    using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSetting", "Account"))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Name", @Model.Settings[index].Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Value", setting.Value)</td>
            @Html.Hidden("ID", setting.ID)
            @Html.Hidden("AccountID", Model.AccountInfo.AcctID)
            <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of different variations on the syntax but cannot seem to get it right.
Suggestions, solutions and resources welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("AccountSettings.Name", @Model.Settings[index].Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("AccountSettings.Value", setting.Value)</td>
        @Html.Hidden("AccountSettings.ID", setting.ID)
        @Html.Hidden("AccountSettings.AccountID", Model.AccountInfo.AcctID)
        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Your view model is AccountDetailViewRequest of which Name, Value, etc aren't properties.

It'd be tidier if you did something like this:

```
@foreach (var setting in Model.Settings)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSetting", "Account"))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => setting.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => setting.Value)</td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => setting.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => setting.AcctID)
            <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Note that I improvised the above code and you might need to tweak it to work